# OneDrive - How to retrieve authorization access data?

Tags: android, permissions, authorization, onedrive

I develop an android application which use OneDrive API. When I connect to OneDrive, it asks me to authenticate and show an authorization page (with permission to access to my data on the cloud).

My problem is : Every time I upload data on the cloud, the application shows me the authorization page. I would like this page to not appear every time. How can we find that it already recorded please ?

Thank a lot !

Comment: Is this using the LiveSDK-for-Android?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how use it to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the LiveSDK for Andriod, there is an assumption that the user is authenticated at all times when using the application, in order to preserve this flow, we require that you call LiveAuthClient.initialize(...) to renew the user credentials (without any user input) or call LiveAuthClient.login(...) in order to perform an interactive login (User entering username/password).

In the LiveSDK sample apps we see this implemented with a startup activity called SignInActivity.java  Here are the relevant excerpts to perform the silent credentials renewal:

```
protected void onStart() {
   super.onStart();
   mAuthClient.initialize(Arrays.asList(Config.SCOPES), new LiveAuthListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAuthError(LiveAuthException exception, Object userState) {
         mInitializeDialog.dismiss();
         showSignIn();
         showToast(exception.getMessage());
      }

      @Override
      public void onAuthComplete(LiveStatus status, LiveConnectSession session, Object userState) {
         mInitializeDialog.dismiss();
         if (status == LiveStatus.CONNECTED) {
            launchMainActivity(session);
         } else {
            showSignIn();
         }
      }
   });
}
```

The launchMainActivity() function moves the user into the primary application code, this would be where your application starts in earnest.  To see the full details of this sign in activity take a look at the sample app [SignInActivity.java in Github](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Android/blob/master/sample/src/com/microsoft/live/sample/SignInActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works when I write LiveAuthClient.initialize(...) and just after LiveAuthClient.login(...).

Comment: But... When I close and relaunch the application, I have the same problem. It ask me to accept permissions again (but not to authentificate me). So, it keep account informations but not permissions. How can I do please ? I looked at your sample app but I have not find informations about it.

Comment: You'll want to include the wl.offline_access scope into your requests, this will cause the scope check information to be cached so it isn't requested on every authentication attempt.

Comment: It was wl.offline_access scope I forgot. Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: And just one last question : After the user is connected, how I can get account informations about connected user (email address for example). Thanks for all.